# Getting wifi vendor details using wifi macaddress

Tags: php, ieee

I need to get wifi vendor details based on wifi mac address

For eg. mac address - E0:43: DB and vendor is - Shenzhen ViewAt Technology Co., Ltd.

To achieve this I have used `https://macvendors.com/` official API with the below code

```
$mac_address = "A2:8C:FD:5A:71:64";

 $url = "https://api.macvendors.com/" . urlencode($mac_address);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  if($response) {
    echo "Vendor: $response";
  } else {
    echo "Not Found";
  }
```

But the problem is most of the mac vendor lookup API providers have very less no.of details in DB so for a lot of records I'm getting not found response from them

please suggest me that where or in which website I'll get wifi vendor details lookup master data?

I searched on this website also `https://standards.ieee.org/` but didn't get master data.

Thanks.